# How to customize Web-editor Top-menu in Odoo v13?

Tags: javascript, module, odoo, summernote, odoo-13

I have created a new module ("webeditor_custom") to customize Odoo v13 Web editor Top menu to add custom font-sizes in the existing menu items.

[image]

The files in my module "webeditor_custom" are :

1. templates/assets.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<odoo>

<template id="summernote_cust" name="My summernote assets" inherit_id="web_editor.summernote">

<xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/webeditor_custom/static/src/js/summernote_cust.js"></script>

</xpath>

</template>

</odoo>
```

2. In /static/src/js/ directory, i have my summernote_cust.js file :

```
odoo.define('web_editor.summernote_cust', function (require) {

'use strict';

var core = require('web.core');

var editor = require('web_editor.summernote');

require('summernote/summernote'); // wait that summernote is loaded

var _t = core._t;

var options = $.summernote.options;

options.fontSizes = [_t('Default'), 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 21, 24, 28, 32, 36, 42, 49, 56, 63];

return $.summernote;

});
```

3. my  **manifest**.py file:

```
{
    "name": "Web editor custom",
    "summary": "Add font-sizes to the top-menu of the web editor",
    "version": "13.0.2.0.1",
    "installable": True,
    "depends": ["web_editor"],
    "data": ["templates/assets.xml"],
}
```

After installing my module, i get this error (popup) displayed on the first load of my homepage:

***"Error: Service web_editor.summernote_cust already defined"***

Thank you if you have a way to deal with it (summernote on odoo v13) or a workaround !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add your script to the `assets_wysiwyg` bundle, so it will be added after all the [summernote](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web_editor/views/editor.xml#L14) scripts

***Example:***

```
<template id="summernote_cust" name="My summernote assets" inherit_id="web_editor.assets_wysiwyg">
    <xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/webeditor_custom/static/src/js/summernote_cust.js"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>
```